# ADC pin current consumption

Tags: adc

I am using a voltage divider to read about 9V. This divider n/w is connected to an ADC (analogue pin). Now, I am concerned about the wattage of the resistors in the divider n/w. I am using a KL04 Freescale ARM chip. I bring the voltage from 9V to about 2.5V via 10k and 3k n/w. When reading the current, what is the current that is sunk into my pin? The max of each pin is 25mA. Will the controller sink 25mA each time while reading this pin? I am a bit confused.

Kindly advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pin of the ADC will not take that current unless the voltage on that pin is taken above the supply rail to the chip. Your potential divider ensures it doesn't do that in two ways. Firstly it is a potential divider and therefore will reduce the real input's voltage to a lower level and secondly the impedance of the resistor means the raw input voltage would have to be ridiculously high to generate 25mA.